# Property of real functions when derivative approaches zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a question from my exam in Calculus 1.

> **Problem 6**
>
> Let $f: [0,\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$.
>
> a) Show that for $n \in \mathbb{N}: \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( f(n+1) - f(n)\right) = 0$.
>
> b) Is $f$ necessarily bounded? Justify your answer.

I started (a) with

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 0 $$

But how does that help when $h \to 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

For question a, use the Mean Value Theorem.

For question b, the answer is *no*, e.g., consider $f:x\mapsto\sqrt{1+x}$.

Answer (score 2):

To solve (a), apply the MVT: for some $\xi_n \in (n,n+1)$,
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(\xi_n).
$$
Now let $n \to +\infty$.